# WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.Read() Function not loading Fields

Tags: c#, pdf, loading, field, abcpdf

I have been attempting to load, edit and save Adobe Acrobat PDF fields and I have been running into problems loading Adobe Acrobat Fields. Currently I am using C#/Windows Forms and WebSupergoo's ABCpdf library specfically the WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.Read() function.

The code runs fine but when all is said and done the Doc object has no fields in the instanced object.

Presumably they should be in Doc.Form.Fields

The code is quite simply

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.Read("Test.pdf");
```

Then I should be able to access fields by

```
theDoc.Form["FieldName"]
```

WebSupergoo says that ABCpdf8 should support Adobe Acrobat 9.0 files.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `theDoc.Form.Fields["FieldName"];` to get the field instead of form.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I hadn't received anything on this in so long I forgot about it. After more research on the subject I found there is a theDoc.Form.GetFieldNames() which returns the fields in an array which worked for my purposes.

Comment: Youre welcome. Please verify an answer to close this answer - maybe you can write your own solution down.